# pandas cut multiple columns with labels?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to cut and label the values in multiple columns. Basically this:

```
df[numericColumn] = pd.cut(df[numericColumn], 3, labels=["small", "medium", "big"])
```

I found this code (which works) but doesn't do the labelling I want, when I replace bin with labelling it errors out and says I need to include a bin

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4))
df.apply(pd.cut, bins=[0,0.5,1])
```

Is there a way to cut label multiple columns in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So pulling this apart a little to show what is going on.  You will see that you can set up the bins and then do the cut row by row, then change the result of the cut back to the category names that you want to use.

```
# set up a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4))
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']

# set up the intervals
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 0.33), (0.33, 0.66), (0.66, 1)])

# do the cut on col1 for example
x = pd.cut(df["col1"].to_list(),bins)

# change the name of the catagories
x.categories = ['small','medium','large']
# put it back
df['col1'] = x
```

gives

```
    col1    col2        col3        col4
0   large   0.589432    0.545828    0.257144
1   medium  0.625025    0.087607    0.548300
2   small   0.538186    0.057027    0.023201
3   medium  0.686324    0.027694    0.819753
4   medium  0.850623    0.977317    0.782361
5   large   0.375888    0.209709    0.903763
6   medium  0.094957    0.583052    0.534926
7   large   0.101968    0.863916    0.929300
8   large   0.612073    0.005553    0.723863
9   large   0.814393    0.327281    0.463976
```

and if you want to iterate through the whole dataframe

```
# set up a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4))
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']

# set up the intervals
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 0.33), (0.33, 0.66), (0.66, 1)])
names = ['small','medium','large']

for col in df.columns:
    x = pd.cut(df[col].to_list(),bins)
    x.categories = names
    df[col] = x
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul. This is really cool. I have over 100 columns, is it possible to do this in bulk? or iterate around every column?

Comment: I put in the function to go through the dataframe via columns, you can also write a function and apply it by columns.

Comment: Thank you, seems logical to me. For some reason all my dad is coming out as NaN when I run this. I think it's something to do with my data.

Comment: Strange, I've narowed this down to the bins command. If I print x (without converting to names ) the entire list becomes NA. It's strange, I've tried to do fillna but still the same problem -   bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 0.33), (0.33, 0.66), (0.66, 1)])

  x = pd.cut(df[column].to_list(),bins)

Comment: I think I figured it out. I think your code assumes it's already in percentages. I ran a minMax scaler on the data and now it seems to be working.

Comment: Hurrah!  I was looking at how that could be wrong...

Comment: It happens. Thank you for the awesome answer. I wish I reached out 6 hours earlier so I wouldn't have wasted so much time.